# Can I set a calculated formula in a new column in SQL?

Tags: sql, formula

I need to have a column that shows minimum value based on values in other columns.

For example, I have table:`TEST` with the following columns:

`Date`| `Name` | `Qty`

Some of the names are repetitive in different dates.

I want to have a 4th column that shows the minimum value per that Name regardless the date (i.e. the minimum value in the sample database).

What I have tried so far:

```
UPDATE TABLE TEST
ADD LOWEST VARCHAR NULL
SET LOWEST
SELECT Top 1 Name, Qty
FROM TEST
GROUP BY Name
order by Qty Asc
```

However it is not working.

Comment: one question... that min value will be set for all the columns that have same name right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have one small example for you:

```
create table TEMP(name varchar(250),value int)
insert into TEMP
values ('aaa',10), ('aaa',30),('bbb',15),('bbb',20)


alter table TEMP add minimum int 


update t 
set t.minimum = tt.minimum
select * from TEMP t join 
(select min(value) as minimum ,name from TEMP group by name ) tt on t.name=tt.name
```

Comment: Thanks dear, but may i ask what does "update t" do? the second part of the query work fine

Comment: Well if the answer is correct mark it as the solution. That part of the syntax just select the table to update. See below that t is the alias of Temp table

Comment: thanks, one more question bro, what if i did not want to show the name column again, what modification to the query should i do. thanks

Comment: Give me the wanted return.